# Rails render one of two different pages every other time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect

In a Rails controller, can I *redirect_to* one of two separate pages on every other page load?

Something that would do this type of thing:

```
class HomePageController < ApplicationController
   def index
      50% of the page-loads do
         redirect_to '/foo'
      else
         redirect_to '/bar'
      end
   end
end
```

Is this type of stuff possible in a Rails controller?  Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean, you want to render two pages in one controller at the same time? If that is you purpose, use partials instead of doing on controller. If you want to redirect in a route if your condition satisfies? Yes, you can do it like what your code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can conditionally redirect within your Rails controllers and as such the following is a "real" example of your pseudo-code:

```
def index
  if rand(2) == 1
    redirect_to '/foo'
  else
    redirect_to '/bar'
  end
end
```

However, if you're looking to do multivariate testing, this is not a full solution. The page could change even when the same user visits it twice, which could be very disorienting. You might want to look into gems like [split](https://github.com/splitrb/split), or at least store which page the user is seeing in the session (or a cookie).

Comment: This wouldn't flip every other visit, but instead would have a 50% chance of flipping each time.  OP wasn't very clear, but I don't think this is what he wants.

Comment: @KieranE: yeah, totally depends on OP's intent. I felt that the fact it was on `HomePageController`'s `#index` action suggests he just wants to test out two different home pages.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'd need to persist this sort of thing in a DB or a session, since controllers are totally ignorant of this sort of thing.

But do you want it to serve a new page every other request, or every other request to a specific user?  If `user A` visits, then `user B` visits, should they both see `page 1` or should `user b` see `page 2`?  This will tell you whether you need to use sessions or a DB.

Anyway, here's some pseudocode of what you should do (assuming that every other request flips, regardless of user)

```
def index
  # A currently non-existent model that tracks visits
  if Visitor.count.even?
    render 'page_1'
  else
    render 'page_2'
  end

  Visitor.create(<whatever information you want to store>)
end
```